# Dynamically give all attributes using haml-coffee

Tags: hamlc

Example template:

```
%input{ @attributes }
```

Example rendering:

```
@attributes = {:foo => :bar}
render :example_template
```

Example output with haml:

```
<input foo="bar">
```

I tried to achieve this with haml-coffe with `JST['example_template']({attributes: {foo: 'bar'}}` but it doesn't seem to work like I expected.

How one can give all attributes completely dynamically with haml-coffee?

Answer (score 2):

Specify all attributes by giving an object is not supported in Haml-Coffee, you need to explicitly define all attribute known at compile time:

```
%input{ foo: @attributes['bar'] }
```

and render the template with

```
JST['example_template'](attributes: { foo: 'bar' })
```

If you need to define all attributes freely, then I suggest you to set it in your view, e.g.

```
class ExampleView extends Marionette.View

  ui:
    foo: 'input[foo]'

  onRender: ->
    @ui.foo.attr(@attributes)
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with haml_coffee_assets?

Comment: haml_coffee_assets is a template engine and doesn't provide anything to manage your web apps like Backbone, Ember, etc.